# Using Hadoop DistributedCache with archives

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Hadoop's [DistributedCache](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) documentation doesn't seem to sufficently describe how to use the distributed cache. Here is the example given:

```
 // Setting up the cache for the application

 1. Copy the requisite files to the FileSystem:

 $ bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal lookup.dat /myapp/lookup.dat  
 $ bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal map.zip /myapp/map.zip  
 $ bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal mylib.jar /myapp/mylib.jar
 $ bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal mytar.tar /myapp/mytar.tar
 $ bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal mytgz.tgz /myapp/mytgz.tgz
 $ bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal mytargz.tar.gz /myapp/mytargz.tar.gz

 2. Setup the application's JobConf:

 JobConf job = new JobConf();
 DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("/myapp/lookup.dat#lookup.dat"), 
                               job);
 DistributedCache.addCacheArchive(new URI("/myapp/map.zip", job);
 DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/myapp/mylib.jar"), job);
 DistributedCache.addCacheArchive(new URI("/myapp/mytar.tar", job);
 DistributedCache.addCacheArchive(new URI("/myapp/mytgz.tgz", job);
 DistributedCache.addCacheArchive(new URI("/myapp/mytargz.tar.gz", job);

 3. Use the cached files in the Mapper
 or Reducer:

 public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase  
 implements Mapper<K, V, K, V> {

   private Path[] localArchives;
   private Path[] localFiles;

   public void configure(JobConf job) {
     // Get the cached archives/files
     File f = new File("./map.zip/some/file/in/zip.txt");
   }

   public void map(K key, V value, 
                   OutputCollector<K, V> output, Reporter reporter) 
   throws IOException {
     // Use data from the cached archives/files here
     // ...
     // ...
     output.collect(k, v);
   }
 }
```

I've been searching around for over an hour trying to figure out how to use this. After piecing together a few other SO questions, here's what I came up with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Job job = new Job(new JobConf(), "Job Name");
    JobConf conf = job.getConfiguration();
    DistributedCache.createSymlink(conf);
    DistributedCache.addCacheArchive(new URI("/ProjectDir/LookupTable.zip", job);
    // *Rest of configuration code*
}

public static class MyMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> 
{
    private Path[] localArchives;

    public void configure(JobConf job)
    {
        // Get the cached archive
        File file1 = new File("./LookupTable.zip/file1.dat");   
        BufferedReader br1index = new BufferedReader(new FileInputStream(file1));
    }

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    { // *Map code* }
}
```

- **Where am I supposed to call the `void configure(JobConf job)` function?**
- **Where do I use the `private Path[] localArchives` object?**
- **Is my code in the `configure()` function the correct way to access files within an archive and to link a file with a BufferedReader?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer your questions w.r.t new API and common practices in use for distributed cache

- **Where am I supposed to call the void configure(JobConf job) function?**

Framework will call **protected void setup(Context context)** method once at beginning of every map task, the logic associated with using cache files is usually handled here. For example, reading file and storing data in variable to be used in map() function which is called after setup()

- **Where do I use the private Path[] localArchives object?**

It will be typically used in setup() method to retrieve path of cache files . Something like this.

```
  Path[] localArchive =DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration());
```

- **Is my code in the configure() function the correct way to access
  files within an archive and to link a file with a BufferedReader?**

Its missing a call to method to retrive path where cache files are stored (shown above). Once the path is retrieved the file(s) can be read as below.

```
FSDataInputStream in = fs.open(localArchive);
BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Comment: Do the `setup` and `configure` functions go inside the `Mapper` class? `JobConf job` will be out of scope there. Also, I'm getting undefined symbol errors for `DistributedCache` and `URI`. Any idea what I'm missing? Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Setup is from new API and used in mapper class.I would recommend you to start using new API here http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html